# MapView showing in Ocean in ios 5

Tags: google-maps, ios5, mkmapview, mapkit

I had an app which was working fine till I updated to ios 5.0. After update map is displayed in ocean. I am not sure what went wrong.
Heres the code I am using

[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];

```
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
region.center.latitude = deleg.selectedVenue.latitude;
region.center.longitude = deleg.selectedVenue.longitude;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

How can I do this properly in ios 5.0?
Thanks

Comment: How and where is deleg.selectedVenue set?  What method is this code in?  That var is probably nil here for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code snippet of mine that works under iOS5. Feel free to ask any questions.

```
// grab the location from persistent store
CLLocation *loc = [store currentLocation];


CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
float zoom;

// it will be NULL on first launch, so initialize to someplace interesting.
if (!loc) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D longPointLightLocation;
    longPointLightLocation.latitude = 42.033126;
    longPointLightLocation.longitude = -70.168621;
    // center the map so the initial zoom when the GPS kicks in is from HERE, not the default
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:longPointLightLocation animated:NO];
    zoomLocation = longPointLightLocation;
    zoom = 50;    // on first launch, zoom way out
} else {
    zoomLocation.latitude = loc.coordinate.latitude;
    zoomLocation.longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude;
    zoom = 2;
}

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, zoom*METERS_PER_MILE, zoom*METERS_PER_MILE);
[mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that deleg.selectedVenue is a valid coordinate, e.g.

```
if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(deleg.selectedVenue)) {
    // add to your mapView
}
else {
    NSLog(@"coordinate is invalid");
}
```

where CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid is a function declared in the Core Location framework.